# Add a page curl animation to a NSView?

Tags: cocoa, core-animation, nsview

I see there are built-in api for ios to make a page curl animation to an UIView,but what should i do to make the page curl animation to a NSView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Quartz Composer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/QuartzComposer/qc_intro/qc_intro.html); it also has a built-in page curl animation.